# c++ while loop repeats

Tags: c++

I have the following code. When something like `jackpot` is inputted, it prints out the cout 8 times, once for each character. Why is it doing this? Information is a structure and number is an integer.

```
do {
        cout <<"Please input a valid number."<< endl;
        cin>>information.number;
        if (!cin)
          {
             cin.clear();
             cin.ignore();
          }
    }
while(information.number> 12 || information.number< 1);
```

Comment: Look again: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a maximum ignore length length and an ignore `delimiter`:

```
do {
        cout <<"Please input a valid number."<< endl;
        cin>>information.number;
        if (!cin)
          {
             cin.clear();
             cin.ignore(1024, '\n'); // ignore up to 1024 chars. until '\n'
          }
    }
while(information.number> 12 || information.number< 1);
```